# NSFetchedResultsController with multiple section logic

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a list of items that are added to a shopping list.  Each item has a department, and a flag to say whether it has been collected or not.

I would love to use a single table view to display this.  The problem is, I need to group the sections by department, and then add a final additional section at the bottom for collected items (regardless of departments).

I can create a fetchedResultsController filtering out collected = yes and sorting by department easily enough.  But I need this additional section appended with those items where collected = yes.

Should I be trying to create a fetchedResultsController with a sophisticated query to do this?  Or try to manually add a section and some rows?  If so, from where?  A second FRC? Is it possible to have two FRCs feed into a single tableview?

Answer (score 1):

Ben,

The NSFetchedResultsController is designed to provide a single fetch to fill a table view. But you have the choice of how that data is fed into the table view. You can manually translate the fetched items where ever you want. You can add sections, extra rows, whatever. That is why they surface the update of the model in the delegate. They give you the chance to make those adjustments.

Hence, if you construct your model such that a single fetch does the job, then you have a great deal of flexibility on how you use it.

Andrew

Comment: SO are you proposing I stick with a fairly simple predicate and change the data after fetching?  Where would be an appropriate place to do this?  Or by a 'single fetch' do you mean I should devise a more complex query that retrieves the data exactly as I want it?

Comment: Ben, I said nothing about changing the data. You have total control of how you display the data from the controller. For example, if you wanted to put a search box at the top of the table view, as Apple's contacts list does, then you will need to adjust the row and section number of every item coming from the controller to take this into account. It is straightforward. This is also why you have to manually connect the controller to the table view. The other thing to remember is that the controller has limits. Sometimes the right answer is to listen for the merge notifications yourself. Andrew

Comment: I'm sorry, none of this makes sense to me.  I can't really respond to it.  It seems clear that I use a single fetch request and modify the objects before they are displayed, but I still don't know how to section them by two different criteria.

Comment: Ben, you declare sections as you always would by telling the table view that you have, say, 1 more section than the FRC gives you. Then, you populate those cells the way you would normally do. Or you can dispense with the FRC altogether and just maintain the set of nested arrays of objects yourself. Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I have tried to make my question more specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997387/tableview-with-two-instances-of-nsfetchedresultscontroller I think you are sending me in the right direction, but maybe I have just missed a small piece.

Answer (score 0):

**sectionKeypathName** is available which takes a parameter to decide how many sections should be there. If you pass nil, there will be only one section but if you pass some **sectionKeypathName** in **FetcherResultsController** and set the first **sortDescriptor** same as the sectionKeyPathName, you will get different sections in fethedResultsControllerDelegate. That **sectionKeypathName** must be attribute in an entity you are fetching.

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sectionView", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: mainContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionView", cacheName: nil)
```