# TableView with two instances of NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

After days of research and re-coding I am pretty much stumped.  My goal is to get a test app running with a single tableview populated from two separate fetchedResultControllers.

I have a series of items on a shopping list, each with a department and a boolean 'collected' flag.  Uncollected items should be listed by department, followed by a single section containing all collected items (regardless of department).  As a user checks off uncollected items, they should move down to the 'collected' section.  If s/he un-checks a collected item, it should move back into its correct department.

[image]

To achieve the first part (uncollected items), I set up a simple fetchedResultsController that fetches all items where collected = NO, and sectioned the results by department:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)firstFRC {
    // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
    if (firstFRC == nil) {

        // Create the fetch request for the entity.
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        // fetch items
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // only if uncollected
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(collected = NO)"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        // sort by name
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // fetch results, sectioned by department
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"department" cacheName:nil];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.firstFRC = aFetchedResultsController;
    }

    return firstFRC;
}
```

I set the number of rows, sections, and section headers as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return firstFRC.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[firstFRC.sections objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[firstFRC sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}
```

I also use the boilerplate controllerWillChangeContent, didChangeObject, and controllerDidChangeContent to add/remove cells as the FRC's change.

For brevity, I won't include the code for displaying the cell, but I essentially pull the correct item based on the cell's index path, set the text/subtitle of the cell, and attach one of two checkmark images, depending on whether the item is collected or not.  I also wire up this image (which is on a button) to toggle from checked to unchecked when it is touched, and update the item accordingly.

This part all works fine.  I can view my list of items by department, and when I mark one as collected, I see it drop off the list as expected.

Now I attempted to add the bottom section, containing all of the collected items (in a single section).  First I set up a second fetchedResultsConroller, this time to fetch only uncollected items, and without sectioning.  I also had to update the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections - add one for 'collected' section
    return firstFRC.sections.count + 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section
    if (section < firstFRC.sections.count) {
        return [[firstFRC.sections objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }
    else {
        return secondFRC.fetchedObjects.count;
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section < firstFRC.sections.count) {
        return [[[firstFRC sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
    }
    else{
        return @"Collected";
    }
}
```

I then updated the cellForRowAtIndexPath in a similar fashion, so that the item I retrieve comes from the right FRC:

```
    Item *item;
    if (indexPath.section < firstFRC.sections.count) {
        item = [firstFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        item = [secondFRC objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item name]];

…rest of cell configuration
```

This works great when I launch.  The tableview displays exactly as anticipated:

[image]

**The Problem (finally)**

The (first) problem comes when I select the checkmark for an uncollected item.  I expect the item to be removed from the department it is listed under, and moved to the 'collected' section.  Instead, I get:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in
>   that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows
>   inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus
>   or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved
>   in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

If I attempt the opposite, then I receive a different error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   1]'

I suspect that in both cases there is a problem with consistency with the number of sections/rows in the FRCs and the tableview when an item moves from one FRC to the other.  Although that second error makes me think there is maybe a simpler problem related to my retrieval of items.

Any direction or ideas would be appreciated.  I can provide more of my code if it would help, and have also created a small test app with a single view to demonstrate the issue.  I can upload it if necessary, but mostly I wanted to test the issue in a small scale sandbox.

**Update - additional code requested**

As requested, this is what happens when a checkmark is touched:

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    Item *item;
    if (indexPath.section < firstFRC.sections.count) {
        item = [firstFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        item = [secondFRC objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;  

    if (![item collected]) {
        [item setCollected:YES];        
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if ([item collected]){
        [item setCollected:NO];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![item.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving collected items");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the department names are slightly off in the screenshot.  I forgot to use the dept as the first sort descriptor.

Comment: How are you reloading your table?

Comment: Post the code that gets called when a checkmark is tapped.

Comment: erurainon - I believe this is taken care of by         aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self (first code block)?

Comment: jcm - Updated with the code you requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I think I might have cracked it.  As is often the case, stripping it down and reading just a few comments pointed me in the right direction.

When I get to the delegate method controllerDidChangeObject, I attempt to insert a row at the indexPath provided (for the 'checked' item).  Except that when inserting into my additional section, this indexPath has no awareness of the fact that there are a bunch of other sections before it.  So it receives section 0 and attempts to insert there.  Instead, if the indexPath comes from the second FRC, I should be incrementing the section number by the number of sections in the first FRC's table.  So, I replaced:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath { 

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        break;
```

with

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

        if ([controller.sectionNameKeyPath isEqualToString:@"department"]) {
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        else {
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:firstFRC.sections.count]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];         }
        break;
```

I will need to do this for each of insert, delete, update etc.  I will mark this as the answer after I have validated this and to allow time for other comments.

Comment: You can also check if([controller isEqualTo: self.firstFetchedResultsController])

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are seeing mean that your `UITableView` reloads itself before BOTH your `NSFetchedResultsController`s do. The codes you posted are probably correct. I suspect that the problem is in one of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods.

Comment: Do you mean controllerWillChangeContent, etc?  These I ripped wholesale from Apple's demo.